# TAB completion with .bash_history

Tags: bash, command-history, tab-completion

I usually use PageUp/PageDown to search through .bash_history given a prefix.

However, I regularly catch me pressing TAB multiple times before realizing that I need to use PageUp/PageDown in this particular case.

Is there a way to integrate .bash_history search in TAB completion?

Comment: I don't know if I understand exactly what you mean, but to reverse lookup commands in the history you use `Ctrl-R` and start typing, if you have typed the command and you need a previous one (other than the one showing) you press `Ctrl+R` again. Once you see the command you need to run you just press enter, if you need to slightly edit, tab, or left/right arrows. Does it help?

Comment: There are too different systems for searching back in history: PageUp/PageDown and Ctrl-R. I'm talking about the former one. And instead of using PageUp/PageDown I would prefer to simply use Tab completion instead --- Ctrl-R is unrelated.